# enviar una alert al seleccionar un select

Tags: javascript

Necesito enviar una alerta al realizar una comprobación cuando el cliente seleciona un select de un formulario, las opciones del select están cargadas dinámicamente con un array. pero no logro hacer la condicion dentro de esa función.

```
   addOptions("pecados", array);

        //  agregar opciones a un <select>
        function addOptions(domElement, array) {

            var select = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];

            for (value in array) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = array[value];
                option.setAttribute('value', [value]);
                select.add(option);
                
            }
            var pecado = document.getElementById("pecado").value;
        
            for(i = 0; i < pecado.lenght; i++){
                if(pecado == 1){
                    alert("Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto");
                }
                if(pecado == 2){
                    alert("Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto");
                }
                if(pecado == 3){
                    alert("Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto");
                }
                if(pecado == 4){
                    alert("Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto");
                }
                if(pecado == 5){
                    alert("Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto");
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr esto tendríamos que hacer un evento `onChange` en el `select`, y pasar parametros a una función dependiendo de la opcion que haya sido pulsada. Así:

```js
function getval(sel)
{
    alert(sel.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
</select>
```